# Get Dynamic Application URL

Tags: java

In my application, when user registers , a link is sent to user's email id. I want to send dynamic url of that application i.e

Production server: https://example.com/APP/
Test server: https://test.example.com/APP/
Local: http://LOCAL_IP:LOCAL_PORT/APP/

Production and Test server are behind proxy server.

I am using following to generate url. This works fine for local but for test and production it is generating url with actual IP and port. I want to generate like https://test.example.com/APP/,https://example.com/APP/ respectively/

```
final String PROTOCOL = httpRequest.getScheme()+"://";
final String REMOTE_HOST = httpRequest.getLocalAddr();
final String PORT = ":"+httpRequest.getServerPort();
final String CONTEXT = httpRequest.getContextPath();
String url = "<a href='"+ PROTOCOL + REMOTE_HOST + PORT + CONTEXT + "' >" +
                            "Click Here to Proceed</a>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called Reverse DNS Lookup. See this [article](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/reverse_dns_lookup_and_java.html).

But frankly, just read the domain name from a property file and be done with it. There's no reason to complicate the solution, unless you're paid by the hour. When user clicks on the URL, the usual DNS resolution will happen and they'll hit your server. In fact, in a corporate environment, it's very likely that your internal server IP will resolve to a domain name that's not reachable by a user from outside the corp network.

I noticed you'd tagged your question with Spring (which I removed, because your question actually has nothing to do with Spring), so reading the domain name based on environment is a piece of cake.See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).